# Struggling implementing loops using array oriented programming

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas

I am having trouble wrapping my head around loops in pandas/numpy.  take for example this code

```
import pandas as pd

eurusd = pd.read_csv('EURUSD.csv',index_col='Date',parse_dates=True,usecols=['Date','High','Low','Open','Close'])
gbpusd = pd.read_csv('GBPUSD.csv',index_col='Date',parse_dates=True,usecols=['Date','High','Low','Open','Close'])
audusd = pd.read_csv('AUDUSD.csv',index_col='Date',parse_dates=True,usecols=['Date','High','Low','Open','Close'])


eurusd['MovingAvg'] = pd.rolling_mean(eurusd.Close,100)
gbpusd['MovingAvg'] = pd.rolling_mean(gbpusd.Close,100)
audusd['MovingAvg'] = pd.rolling_mean(audusd.Close,100)
```

How would I implement logic that says

```
if the eurusd.Close is less than the eurusd.MovingAvg 
AND if gbpusd.Close is less than the gbpusd.MovingAvg
AND if audusd.Close is GREATER than the audusd.MovingAvg
then set some condition to TRUE
```

Comment: `if eurusd.Close < eurusd.MovingAvg and gbpusd.Close < gbpusd.MovingAvg and audusd.Close > audusd.MovingAvg`

Comment: that returns ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: `MovingAvg` is a collection of values, you have to choose one to compare to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To illustrate the concept using equities and yahoo finance:

```
import pandas.io.data as web

df = web.DataReader(['F', 'AAPL', 'IBM'], 'yahoo', '2015-01-02', '2016-01-01')['Adj Close']

df = pd.concat([df, 
                pd.rolling_mean(df, window=100).rename(
                    columns={col: col + "_100" for col in df})], 
               axis=1)

df['condition'] = False
df.loc[(df.F < df.F_100) & 
       (df.AAPL < df.AAPL_100) & 
       (df.IBM > df.IBM_100), 'condition'] = True

>>> df.tail()
                  AAPL          F         IBM    AAPL_100      F_100     IBM_100 condition
Date                                                                                      
2015-12-24  106.796739  13.692101  135.544053  112.421986  13.616413  140.126056     False
2015-12-28  105.600553  13.567714  134.916580  112.347147  13.611907  139.954141     False
2015-12-29  107.498633  13.615554  137.044105  112.288827  13.607596  139.806220     False
2015-12-30  106.094845  13.558146  136.612715  112.212631  13.602994  139.665642     False
2015-12-31  104.058365  13.481600  134.926379  112.074727  13.595828  139.492368     False

>>> df.condition.sum()
8
```